# Button in Webview Not Working

Tags: android, dropbox

The app that I am making uses dropbox, users must give authorisation to enable us to do this. To do this I load a url in a webview which opens up the login for dropbox then shows a "connect" button.

The first problem I had was the webview was opening the default browser. So I could understand why it was doing this I added a WebViewClient and Overrided the onPageStarted method like so..

```
class AuthCodeWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.d(TAG, url);
    }
}
```

Doing this stopped the default browser opening but I cannot press the button within the html. The webview is recognising it as I  recieve this in the log...

> 07-17 16:13:16.700: V/webview(29778):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent
>   -getEditableSupport  FASLE  07-17 16:13:17.025: I/GATE(29778): DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED

What am I doing wrong so the button doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out it was pretty simple and I figured it out about a minute after I posted. I needed to enable javascript

```
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```